# Trouble with UTF-8 JSON file used in android

Tags: android, json, utf-8

I'm working on an android project and I use JSON to intechange data with server.. Problem is here when I use JSON file with UTF-8 format, some crash happens and the app stops.. and when I don't, it works fine.
I really need to have my files in UTF-8 format to have the correct charecters.
Where am I missing? Thank you in advanced.

Here is my Service Handler class:

public class ServiceHandler {

```
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

and Here is the method I use in main activity:

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SecondActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                try {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Getting JSON Array node
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                }


                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_Title);
                    String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);



                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_Title, title);
                    contact.put(TAG_CONTENT, content);
                    contact.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    conatctlist.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                SecondActivity.this, contactlist,
                R.layout.list_item_2, new String[] { TAG_Title, TAG_CONTENT,
                TAG_DATE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.date });

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}//end getContacts
```

Comment: _some crash happens and the app stops_ - post the stacktrace, it's really hard to guess what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

May be, You have to define HttpClient like this...(Not Tested)

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
params.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```